# failed in installing paddlehub and onnx

Tags: python, onnx

**My computer system is Windows 10,
python version is 3.10.2,
pip version is 22.1.**

I try in cmd.exe for ' pip install paddlehub ',but it failed at the last hint as:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for onnx
Failed to build onnx
 ERROR: Could not build wheels for onnx, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

stacks at onnx?
could I have some advice?
had try google some keywords for 2 days,the 'cmake','GCC',etc,still can't fix it.
Thanks for your time.

here is the whole faillogs in cmd.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: onnx
  Building wheel for onnx (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for onnx (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [94 lines of output]
      fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:772: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'license-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'license_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:459: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running create_version
      running cmake_build
      Using cmake args: ['C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin\\cmake.exe', '-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\\Users\\YI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\include', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\YI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe', '-DBUILD_ONNX_PYTHON=ON', '-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON', '-DONNX_NAMESPACE=onnx', '-DPY_EXT_SUFFIX=.cp310-win_amd64.pyd', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DPY_VERSION=3.10', '-DONNX_USE_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON', '-A', 'x64', '-T', 'host=x64', '-DONNX_ML=1', 'C:\\Users\\YI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7jfedea1\\onnx_9f6dd7ae807b48cdb3af1e3d5618d72e']
      -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
      -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
      -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.23.28106.4
      -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.23.28106.4
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/YI/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe (found suitable version "3.10.2", minimum required is "3.10")
      -- Found PythonLibs: C:/Users/YI/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/libs/python310.lib (found suitable version "3.10.2", minimum required is "3.10")
      Generated: C:/Users/YI/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-7jfedea1/onnx_9f6dd7ae807b48cdb3af1e3d5618d72e/.setuptools-cmake-build/onnx/onnx-ml.proto
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:292 (message):
        Protobuf compiler not found
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        CMakeLists.txt:323 (relative_protobuf_generate_cpp)


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/YI/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-7jfedea1/onnx_9f6dd7ae807b48cdb3af1e3d5618d72e/.setuptools-cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 244, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 229, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 281, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 174, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 337, in <module>
          setuptools.setup(
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1229, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1229, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 136, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1229, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "setup.py", line 233, in run
          self.run_command('cmake_build')
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1229, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qi95bprp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "setup.py", line 219, in run
          subprocess.check_call(cmake_args)
        File "C:\Users\YI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin\\cmake.exe', '-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\\Users\\YI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\include', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\YI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe', '-DBUILD_ONNX_PYTHON=ON', '-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON', '-DONNX_NAMESPACE=onnx', '-DPY_EXT_SUFFIX=.cp310-win_amd64.pyd', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DPY_VERSION=3.10', '-DONNX_USE_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON', '-A', 'x64', '-T', 'host=x64', '-DONNX_ML=1', 'C:\\Users\\YI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7jfedea1\\onnx_9f6dd7ae807b48cdb3af1e3d5618d72e']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for onnx
Failed to build onnx
ERROR: Could not build wheels for onnx, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3.10 wheel has not been supported yet for onnx.I find it in otherwebsite.maybe for this reason. 19/5/2022

Comment: I try python 3.8.5 in the same computer ,problem solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).